# Completely restore centOS 7 as it was on first installation ( Factory Reset)

Tags: centos, ssh, vps

I am running cpanel on my CentOS VPS. but now i need to uninstall cpanel from my server and trying to uninstall it. According to experts its difficult to do that because cPanel/WHM makes huge changes in OS core.

So, now i just want to reset the CentOS (kind of factory reset) and want to know if it's possible?

Note: I have only SSH access

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If everything was installed via the yum package manager, you can undo previous commands:

```
# Get all yum commands previously run
yum history list all

# Get the details of the command
yum history info [entry number]

# Undo each command top-down
yum history undo [entry number]
```

Just be careful not to undo the initial system install!

Answer (score 2):

For now I think it is not possible.

For the future you may consider using rear (RElax And Recover). This tool is included in centos distro , and permits reliable and easy full backup-restore operations. 
So that in case of disaster (hw or other), you can restore your OS in a few minutes.

Comment: that means Centos7 sucks big time. I don't have yum installed anymore, not sure why, after some bad manipulations I guess. Then I'm fucked on a system and I have to reinstall all RPM packages one by one, like seriously Ubuntu is SO MUICH BETTER.